# Invalid Session ID from SalesForce REST API

Tags: vb.net, rest, salesforce, restsharp

I'm making a call to the SalesForce REST Api.

However, I have a very weird error. Initially I wrote this in a VB.NET Module file. Everything was working correctly, as soon as I put the method in a class I keep getting the darn `Invalid Session ID` error. The error doesn't seem to suggest which part of the code is failing.

I am using RestSharp to facilitate the call to the SalesForce API, and I know for a fact it works because in the Module file I am able to fetch the data that I need.

I do not understand the rationale about *why it works in the Module file but not in a class file*.

Anyways, here is the code that I've placed in both the class file and the Module file to facilitate the call:

```
        client = New RestClient(_strURI)
        request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password")
        request.AddParameter("client_id", _strClientID)
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", _strClientSecret)
        request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", _strRedirectUrl)
        request.AddParameter("username", _strUserName)
        request.AddParameter("password", _strPassword & _strSecurityToken)
        'Dim response As IRestResponse


        Dim response As IRestResponse = Nothing

        response = client.Execute(request)
        'This is the offending line in the class file..it returns back a HTTP 200 yet gives me that Session Invalid error 


        If response.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.BadRequest Then
            token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TokenResponse)(response.Content)


            Dim listViewResults As String = HttpGet(token.instance_url & "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/listviews", "")
```

I am unsure whether this is a permission issue or more of a programming error; because in both cases all of the authentication strings are the same. At the moment I've hardcoded it to point to a test profile. So I can't pinpoint what exactly I am doing wrong?

Any help would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me,

Anyways shortly after I posted this I went and took a brisk walk outside of the office. Turned out to be a misnomer.

I had the same `HttpGet` method defined in the module file and **forgot** to copy and paste that into the class file. When I actually stepped through it, it threw an `Exception` inside.

Turned out the only fix needed was to put that method into the class file.